# Apply class to specific element inside ngFor

Tags: html, css, angular, ngfor

I have a loop that generate names + icon.

I would that icon only shows on hover.

```
<div class="elm" *ngFor="let element of callWorkflowData?.jobsList">
    <mat-card (mouseover)="hover=true" (mouseleave)="hover=false">{{element}}
        <mat-icon [ngClass]="hover?'show-icon':'hide-icon'" ng aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon">add</mat-icon>
    </mat-card>

</div>
```

Actually the icon became visible on all cards list when I hover only one element.

I would that the icon shows only on the hovered element

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, the same condition applies to the class binding of all icons. That is why they all change at the same time.

You could define a `hoverElement` property in the component class. It would be set to the hovered element on `mouseover` and reset on `mouseleave`. The class binding condition would check if the `element` variable corresponds to that `hoverElement`:

```
<div class="elm" *ngFor="let element of callWorkflowData?.jobsList">
  <mat-card (mouseover)="hoverElement = element" (mouseleave)="hoverElement = null">{{element}}
    <mat-icon [ngClass]="hoverElement === element ? 'show-icon' : 'hide-icon'" ...>add</mat-icon>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-28sglp?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.html) for a demo.

---

Please note that the same result can be achieved with only CSS and the `:hover` selector:

```
mat-card mat-icon {
  color: orange;
}

mat-card:hover mat-icon {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: darkgreen;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-icons-h2y1av?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.css) for a demo.

Comment: @infodev - Did one of these suggestions work for you?